# Setting the value of a variable from build.sbt in the Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sbt, artifactory

I am new to Jenkins and Sbt, I am trying to to set the value of a variable in jenkins declared in build.sbt.
To explain, i am trying to pusblish jars in artifactory repositories.
I have two repositories one for releases and the other for Snapshots.
in build.sbt :

```
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "https://artifactory.mycloud.something.com/artifactory/sbt-handlereleases")
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
resolvers += "Artifactory" at "https://artifactory.mycloud.something.com/artifactory/sbt-handlereleases/"
```

in Jenkins job (build > execute shell) :

```
sbt clean compile package publish
```

this code enables me to publish jars in the releases repository in artifactory.
however, if i want to publish in the snapshots repository, i will have to modify build.sbt with the right url for the snapshot repository (https://artifactory.mycloud.something.com/artifactory/sbt-handlesnapshots).

how can i set a variable in build.sbt ($URL_REPO) and specify it's value in the jenkins job by assigning the url for snapshots or releases?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the repository, you should use the `publishTo` setting. Here is an example from the [Publishing docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Define+the+repository):

```scala
// in build.sbt
publishTo := {
  val nexus = "https://my.artifact.repo.net/"
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  else
    Some("releases"  at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}
```

This switch between the snapshots and releases repositories is based on the `isSnapshot` setting which usually just checks if the `version` setting has `-SNAPSHOT` suffix.

If this works for your use case, this is the way to go. If it doesn't and you need to switch it depending on some external factor (e.g. how you trigger your Jenkins pipeline), you can introduce an environment variable in Jenkins and check it in `publishTo` definition:

```scala
// in build.sbt
publishTo := {
  if (sys.env.get("IS_SNAPSHOT").isDefined)
    Some("snapshots" at "...")
  else
    Some("releases"  at "...")
}
```

Or if you want to set the URL dynamically:

```scala
publishTo := sys.env.get("URL_REPO").map{ url =>
  "publishing repository" at url
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks very much for your answer, the third option worked well for me!